# What's the detailed derivation from equation 126 to 127 (See Figure)? (problem of Lagrange method with vector transpose)?

Tags: vector-spaces, lagrange-multiplier

I am confused of vector transpose, I do not know how to get equation 127.
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$-\sum_{i=1}^m\left(y_i-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x_i}\right)\mathbf{x_i}+\lambda\mathbf{w}=0$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow -\left(\sum_{i=1}^my_i\mathbf{x_i}\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbf{x_i}\mathbf{x_i}^T\right)\mathbf{w}+\lambda\mathbf{w}=0$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbf{x_i}\mathbf{x_i}^T+\lambda\mathbf{I}\right)\mathbf{w}=\sum_{i=1}^my_i\mathbf{x_i}$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow\mathbf{w}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\mathbf{x_i}\mathbf{x_i}^T+\lambda\mathbf{I}\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^m\mathbf{x_j}y_j\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, but why w'x(i)x(i) equals to x(i)x(i)(T)w, what's the related knowledge for this rule?

Comment: For two vectors $\vec{w}$ and $\vec{x}$, whose elements are denoted by indices, we have in the first case: $$(\vec{w}^T\vec{x}\vec{x})_j=\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i\right)\vec{x}\right]_j=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i\right)x_j$$
And in the second case:
$$(\vec{x}\vec{x}^T\vec{w})_j=\left[(x_ax_b)_{ab}\vec{w}\right]_j=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_j w_i$$
where $(x_ax_b)_{ab}$ is the element on the $a$'th row and $b$'th column of the $n\times n$ matrix $\vec{x}\vec{x}^T$, whose value is precisely $x_a\cdot x_b$. Thus you can see that the two expressions above are equivalent.

Comment: @XiTian Another way to see this is using the properties of the dot product:
$$w^Txx=(w\cdot x)x=x(w\cdot x)=x(x\cdot w)=xx^Tw$$